# Real Time Audio Spectrum Analyser for Ubuntu

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa

I know "Sonic Visualiser", from the Ubuntu Software Center, and it is a very good tool!

But... It works with pre-recorded audio files only.

Is there something like that but to work with real time audio?

I mean, some software which works with the audio we are using in real time into our computer (whatever the source was, jack, alsa and/or pulseaudio).

Is there something like this? Where?

Answer (score 1):

You can use real-time Audio input Analyzer with built-in Spectrograms and Widgets online: http://friture.org/

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.